# Java hw help: Superclass and attributes

Tags: java

I have an assignment where I have to display all the attributes of a class.

My question is what can I do to make the code work without having to add an extra attribute to the person object?

I got the code to work but Apparently I am not supposed to make any changes to the original *person* class. Which is:

```
class person
{
String firstName;
String lastName;
int age;

person(String informedFirstName, String informedLastName, int informedAge)
{
    firstName = informedFirstName;
    lastName = informedLastName;
    age = informedAge;
}

String whatIsUp()
{
 return "undetermined";
}
String getName()
{
    return firstName +" "+lastName;
}
String getAge()
{
    String str = String.valueOf(age);
    return str;
}

String getInfo()
{
    return ("Name = "+ getName() + " age="+ getAge());
}
}
```

The working code that I have is:

app class

```
class app

{
  public static void main(String[] args)
 {
student st1 = new student("Zack","Mills",21,".....");
professor p1 = new professor("Fred","Fonseca",44,".....");
TA ta1 = new TA("Paris","Hilton",20,"......");
System.out.println(st1.getInfo());
System.out.println(p1.getInfo());
System.out.println(ta1.getInfo());
 }
}
```

person class:

```
class person
{
String firstName;
String lastName;
int age;
    String status;

person(String informedFirstName, String informedLastName, 
int informedAge, String informedStatus) //< ---- added attribute informedStatus
{
    firstName = informedFirstName;
    lastName = informedLastName;
    age = informedAge;
            status = informedStatus;
}

String whatIsUp()
{
 return "undetermined";
}
String getName()
{
    return firstName +" "+lastName;
}
String getAge()
{
    String str = String.valueOf(age);
    return str;
}
    String getStatus(){
        return status;
    }

String getInfo()
{
    return ("Name = "+ getName() + " age="+ getAge()) + getStatus();
}
```

}

student class:

```
class student extends person
{
String status;
student(String informedFirstName, String informedLastName, int informedAge, String informedStatus)
{
    super(informedFirstName, informedLastName, informedAge, informedStatus);
    if (age <= 25) status = informedStatus = "Traditional";
    else status = informedStatus = "Non-Traditional";
}

String whatIsUp()
{
 int n = 0;
 String b = "..."; 
 n = (int) (Math.random()*2);
 if (n == 0) b = "reading";
 if (n == 1) b = "talking";  
 return b;
}
String getStatus()
{
    return " Status = " + status;
}
}
```

professor class:

```
class professor extends person
{
String status;
professor(String informedFirstName, String informedLastName, int informedAge, String informedStatus)
{
    super(informedFirstName, informedLastName, informedAge, informedStatus);
    status = informedStatus = "Computer Science";
}

String whatIsUp()
{
 int n = 0;
 String b = "..."; 
 n = (int) (Math.random()*2);
 if (n == 0) b = "reading";
 if (n == 1) b = "talking";  
 return b;
}
String getStatus()
{
    return " Degree = " + status;
}
}
```

TA class:

```
class TA extends person
{
String status;
TA (String informedFirstName, String informedLastName, int informedAge, String informedStatus)
{
    super(informedFirstName, informedLastName, informedAge, informedStatus);
    status = informedStatus = "Excellent";
}

String whatIsUp()
{
 int n = 0;
 String b = "..."; 
 n = (int) (Math.random()*2);
 if (n == 0) b = "reading";
 if (n == 1) b = "talking";  
 return b;
}
String getStatus()
{
    return " Communication Skills = " + status;
}
 }
```

Sorry for all the code and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Way too much code, and not sure what you mean by "display all the attributes of a class" (do you mean all the variables?). Also, why are you including two copies of `class Person`, and why is the second one modified even though you said you're not allowed to change it?

Comment: What I mean by "display all attributes of a class is" for example, student would include first/last name, age, and type i.e. traditional non traditional. The second one is modified because I only found out that I was not allowed to modify the code after I wrote my professor.

Comment: The first code is there only as a reference.

Comment: In the future, please make your posts shorter, starting with not including code that you're not allowed to use anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have it all done by making the class from `studen` extends `person` and having the new attribute `status`  in the new class. Doing this you have a class that has all attributes of `person` including the new one added.

Just remove the attribute `status` from person and leave it unchanged as you were required.

In the constructor of `student` pass the attributes of `person` using the `super` keyword.

```
student(String informedFirstName, String informedLastName, int informedAge,
        String informedStatus)
{
    super(informedFirstName, informedLastName, informedAge);
    if (age <= 25) status = informedStatus = "Traditional";
    else status = informedStatus = "Non-Traditional";
}
```

Objects of the class `student` will give you access to all attributes

```
student s = new student("John", "Doe", 25, "some status");
```

Just one addition, please try to respect java naming conventions, class names should start with an upper case letter.

**EDIT**

To have `getInfo()` return a string containing the status too you have to override that method in your subclass `student` and again using the `super` keyword call the `getInfo()` from `person` and concat the `status` to it.

```
@Override
String getInfo()
{
    return super.getInfo() + " " + getStatus(); // or jsut: + " " + status;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The more I work on this problem the more I get confused. If getInfo() in the person class only returns name and age how do I get the status to display without adding another method to the return of getInfo()?

Comment: @user1566796, your're welcome! please see my edit for your next question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the issue in adding one more attribute to person class. However, if you don't want to touch it I'll suggest you an alternative.

Make a class personExtension which extends person. Add the new status attribute to that class.
Now extend the new personExtension class for TA, student and professor.

```
class personExtension extends person
{
    String status;

personExtension(String informedFirstName, String informedLastName, int informedAge, String informedStatus)
{
    super(informedFirstName,informedLastName,informedAge);
    status = informedStatus;
}
}
```